# Qmake -= operator not working correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qt project which I want to include all of my source files bar one.

```
SOURCES += $$files(*.cpp)
SOURCES -= excluded.cpp
```

I have tried using the wildcard directly

```
SOURCES += *.cpp
```

The strange thing is that if i print out the value of `SOURCES` the file is not printed, however it is still built with the rest of the project:

```
message($$SOURCES) # doesn't show excluded.cpp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is my full .pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += $$files(../compiler/src/*.cpp)
SOURCES -= ../compiler/src/main.cpp
SOURCES += test.cpp

INCLUDEPATH = ../compiler/include

HEADERS += $$files(../compiler/include/*.h)

LIBS += -lgtest -lgmock -pthread

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1z
```

Comment: Your first example (using `$$files`) worked for me. `*.cpp` will not work, as thats resolved on a different level. Please show us the full pro file, your error is most likley somewhere else

Comment: If excluded.cpp is not shown in message($$SOURCES) then it shouldn't be built unless you add it somewhere else. Pls make sure it's this file compiled (not the moc_excluded.cpp generated by the qmake from excluded.h for instance).

Comment: @absolute.madness Don't think i'm re-adding it anywhere

Comment: @nitronoid I can only confirm what was said in the first comment: the problem is not in the pro-file (to support this I've built a project with your pro file and some dummy sources - as expected the excluded file wasn't compiled). You could try to remove the build artefacts (Makefile, *.o, etc.) and rebuild anew, probably you've already tried this.